# implementing swipe between tab using tab-host in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

In **Android** can I implement **swipe between tabs** functionality using **tab-host**. Is it possible to use this functionality without **fragments**. When we are targeting older android versions how can we implement this feature. Can someone help me. Thank You!

Comment: May i know why you are going without fragments? Support library will support for all the version of android devices

Comment: you can use fragment in older android version after add support library, in this article can help you http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: No I'm working on an old project and it hasn't used fragments. Just need to implement the functionality. If I'm gonna use fragments, I have had to do a big work. So just wanna know weather I could implement just the functionality. Thank You!

Comment: @kumar_android, probably because Fragments are broken and are overly complex for a simple interface arrangement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use Fragments, go by @vipulmittal answer Or else you want to implement touch listener like SimpleGestureListener based on your requirements. Good example is [here](http://androidexample.com/Swipe_screen_left__right__top_bottom/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118)

Answer (score 5):

The following link should get you started:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

It uses view pager and adds views of each tab int it.
On tab change listener it changes the view in view pager.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is .
Just implement a touch listener on the frame layout and get the x,y and the motion event. if and implement the functionality accordingly.